# Convert matrix to a special dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix

I want to convert a matrix to the following type of dataframe. I appreciate any ideas. Thank you

```
import numpy as np

data = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')
pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The expected dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
inds = np.array(list(map(list, np.ndindex(data.shape))))
rows = inds[:,0]
cols = inds[:,1]
df = pd.DataFrame({"rows":rows, "cols":cols, "value":np.array(data).flatten()})
```

Might not be the fastest but should work.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some operation around `unstack`. I can get *almost* to your desired output via

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
flat_df = df.T.unstack()
```